# Laravel: connecting value in one table to value in another table

Tags: laravel

I am doing a project on Laravel.

I have two tables:

**table 1** - countries with unique ids:

[image]

**table 2** - blog lists:

[image]

My view shows the blog list data with the countries uid.

I would like to show the name instead.

[image]

Comment: can you share the table structures and with some sample date **(AS FORM OF CODE NOT AS IMAGE)**

Comment: Add some code so we can understand

Answer (score 0):

With a very limited info that you have provided, this is expected on your Blog (as assumed) model:

**Blog model:**

```
public function country()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

Then fetching the data from the Blog model:

**Controller:**

```
$blogs = Blog::all();
```

Displaying the results:

**Blade file:**

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
 {{$blog->title}} - {{$blog->country->name}}<br/> 
@enforeach
```